# How to change the keys names in dataset

Tags: dataset

[image]

As you can see from the picture, I want to change the keys names of the list. There are 14314 keys names, but they are all mess, I want to change it with a list of continuous numbers like Range[14314]. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an example, we'll use the built-in Titanic dataset

```
f = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}][GroupBy["class"]];
```

A `Dataset` can be converted to an an `Association`/`List` form by using the `Normal` function, e.g.,

```
Normal[f]
```

[image: output of Normal[f]]

What you want to do is replace the keys and re-convert this into a `Dataset`, which is easily accomplished by:

```
With[
 {values = Values@Normal[f],
  newGroups = Range@Length[f]  },
 Dataset@AssociationThread[newGroups, values]]
```

[image: output of With]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me solve the problem Mr Schrier!